# Replace not working in Encription program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating an encryption program.The scheme works by rotating the vowels in a message as follows:

“a” becomes “e”, “e” becomes “i”, “i” becomes “o”, “o” becomes “u”, “u” becomes “a”.

If a letter is not a vowel, it would be shifted n times.  If n is 5, then
“b” becomes “g”, “c” becomes “h”, “d” becomes “i”,…, ‘x” becomes “d”, “z” becomes “e”
e.g. the letter “break” becomes “gwiep”. To decrypt it, you perform the reverse operation.
Here is my code it, but its only for vowels it doesn't give me the required output.

```
print('Welcome to the data encryption program.')

words = input('Enter your messsage:r ')

for char in words:
    if char == 'a':
        words = words.replace('a','e')
    elif char == 'e':
        words = words.replace('e','i')
    elif char == 'i':
        words = words.replace('i','o')
    elif char == 'o':
        words = words.replace('o','u')
    elif char == 'o':
        words = words.replace('o','u')


print(words)
```

This is the result i get.

```
Enter your messsage: aeiou
uuuuu
```

Comment: Your encryption scheme doesn't work: if n=5 for example, both `i` and `j` will be encoded to `o`, so there's no possible decryption - whatever the value of n.

Comment: There appears to be a bug in the last stanza: you check for 'o' and replace 'o', 'u' two times. I think you probably meant one of them to check for 'u' and replace 'u', 'a' (?) at the end.

Comment: That;s true, I have fixed it already.I am grateful @AustinHastings

Comment: I will be assigning them to a special character. @ThierryLathuille

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`words.replace` will replace all letters in the string, so after the first encounter of `a`, they will be replaced with `e`. Then, whenever there is a `e` encountered, your previously replaced `a` (which is now an `e`), will *also* be translated to `i`, et cetera.

Better is to not use `replace()`, but append each translation to a translated string:

```
print('Welcome to the data encryption program.')

words = input('Enter your messsage: ')
translated = '';

for char in words:
    if char == 'a':
        translated += 'e'
    elif char == 'e':
        translated += 'i'
    elif char == 'i':
        translated += 'o'
    elif char == 'o':
        translated += 'u'
    else:
        translated += char

print(translated)
```

Result:

```
[bart@localhost playground]$ python3 foo.py 
Welcome to the data encryption program.
Enter your messsage: aeiou
eiouu
```

I have to add also that this "encryption" should never be used in a real application.

Comment: Thank you this worked well!!. The program is not being used in an application .There's no need to worry.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use a dictionary:

```
code = {"a":"e", "e":"i", "i":"o", "o":"u", "u":"a"}

word = input("Your word: ")

encoded = [code[w] if w in code else w for w in word]
encoded = ''.join(encoded)
```

First I define a dictionary with your code, I ask for a word and transform it into a list. I replace the elements that should be replaced else I keep the old element in the list comprehension. In the end I join the list to a string.

Comment: Good point! One could argue about readability, but I guess it looks better so I edited it

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your implementation is that you're morphing all of the characters into each other until they all become u's. Your a's become e's, and then your a's and e's become i's, ..., until all the characters are u's.

One way to preserve the characters and swap in place would be to replace them initially with different values, and then convert the new string to what you're looking for. One example is to swap them with capitalized values, and then simply put the string to lowercase for the answer.

Also this doesn't have to be done in a loop, and can be done on the string.

```
print('Welcome to the data encryption program.') 

words = input('Enter your message: ')
words = words.replace('a','E')
words = words.replace('e','I')
words = words.replace('i','O')
words = words.replace('o','U')
words = words.replace('u','A')

words = words.lower()

print(words)
```